# cloudfoundry can not auto configure MySQL when I start sidekiq

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry

I use `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq` to start my backgroud job processor sidekiq in my "*new app*", which is relevant to a rails APP, and it must access the Rails model.

But it failed with a error mysql connection. The Redis connection is reconfigured well, but mysql connection is not.

So how to solve this problem?

--- Added Dec 4, 2012 ---
Use the repo [here](https://github.com/crhan/hztqsk/tree/cf) in branch **cf**

Comment: We need more information about your system and your code to connect to mysql to help you.

Comment: Hi, I have an example of this working. You shouldn't actually need to specify the environment, just run "bundle exec sidekiq", cloud foundry always run in production anyway. Have you checked both services are bound to the application correctly?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at this article: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/03/12/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-ruby-part-1-auto-reconfiguration/

Comment: @DanHigham I don't know why it happened to me. But it does run in the development env if I run `bundle exec sidekiq`

Comment: @durron597 my repo is here at [github](https://github.com/crhan/hztqsk/tree/cf) in branch __cf__. there are three manifests, one for the rails, one for the cronJob and one for the sidekiq

Comment: @durron597 here is the log http://pastebin.com/GqmwtnWw. It doesn't mention mysql auto-reconfiguration.

Comment: @DanHigham And yes, I have bond the mysql service the sidekiq app, see it here http://d.pr/i/Qlyz

Comment: I can't see anything in the logs for the sidkiq worker application that would suggest a MySQL connection error, can you provide an excerpt of the log that would suggest that?

Comment: @DanHigham Debuging this on remote cloudfoundry platform make me crazy! So i decide to give micro Cloud a try

Comment: Looking through the logs, I can see there are some timeout issues when retrieving remote data, perhaps this is the issue. I can also see the migrations run against MySQL in the logs which shows that the binding to MySQL is ok.